# Uploading images/files on multiple platforms at once

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-devices, mobile-development

I'm new to coding mobile applications. May I just ask if you have any **recommendations** on how can I `share` on **multiple mobile apps** in just a `single upload click`? Let's say I want my `current snaps/uploads` on **Snapchat** to be on **Instagram** also and vice-versa.

I'm thinking of running it on the background (?) Or it could be like the tool `Selenium Web`but for this case, it is between mobile applications.

Comment: What would you run in the background? How would you let the user choose to which applications? All very unclear.

Comment: Just asking if it is feasible. An app that uploads all that is in your Snapchat to Instagram story by just a `click of a button`

Comment: You have not made anything clear.

Comment: Here is the process that I have in mind: user `clicks my app's button` -> my app `opens another app` **(Snapchat)** on background -> `downloads the snaps` that I uploaded to it within the day `to Camera roll` -> `opens another app` **(Instagram)** -> `selects 'Add Story'` and `uploads the snaps` that I downloaded from Snapchat to my camera roll

Answer (score 0):

yes u can do it in the background, but you need to take care of the permissions.

Comment: Do what on the background? How would you know to which applications? And which permissions exactly? What a vague answer!